# Switch to new page from one page by click on one link which is dynamic in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a website that has some links which redirect to other pages in a new tab. I am not able to go to the new page opened in new tab.

How can it be done?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the guide [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part on Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE). This will help you solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and what the results were so we can better help you.

Comment: You should specify the language you are using in your question and tags.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you tried to go to page opened on new tab. But here is how you can get hold of page opened in new tab.

```
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(0));
```

once you shift the focus to this new tab, you can validate the page title.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java, following lines of code will work fine:

```
String oldTab = driver.getWindowHandle();
try{
    List<String> newTab = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
    newTab.remove(oldTab);
    driver.switchTo().window(newTab.get(0));
} catch (Exception e) {
    Reporter.log("No new tab found!! " + "Number of tabs currently open = "+driver.getWindowHandles().size(), true); //only if you like this
    throw e; // or whatever you wanna do here
}
```